# Numpy matrix multiplication with array of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have several numpy arrays that I would like to multiply (using `dot`, so matrix multiplication). I'd like to put them all into a numpy array, but I can't figure out how to do it.

E.g.

```
a = np.random.randn((10,2,2))
b = np.random.randn((10,2))
```

So I have 10 2x2 matrices (a) and 10 2x1 matrices (b). What I could do is this:

```
c = np.zeros((10,2))
for i in range(10):
  c[i] = np.dot(a[i,:,:],b[i,:])
```

You get the idea.

But I feel like there's a usage of `dot` or `tensordot` or something that would do this in one line really easily. I just can't make sense of the `dot` and `tensordot` functions for >2 dimensions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
c = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', a, b)
```

`einsum` performs a sum of products. Since matrix multiplication is a sum of products, any matrix multiplication can be expressed using `einsum`. It is based on [Einstein summation notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

The first argument to einsum, `ijk,ik->ij` is a string of `subscripts`.
`ijk` declares that `a` has three axes which are denoted by `i`, `j`, and `k`.

`ik`, similarly, declares that the axes of `b` will be denoted `i` and `k`.

When the subscripts repeat, those axes are locked together for purposes of summation.
The part of the subscript that follows the `->` shows the axes which will remain after summation.

Since the k appears on the left (of the `->`) but disappears on the right, there is summation over `k`. It means that the sum

```
c_ij = sum over k ( a_ijk * b_ik )
```

should be computed. Since this sum can be computed for each `i` and `j`, the result is an array with subscripts `i` and `j`.

Comment: That's great. That works. Would you mind writing just a few sentences about what the first argument means for those of us who don't use this notation?